# groovy script Error

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

I am newbie to groovy. In command prompt (I am not using any IDE), I typed following : (No Problem with environment variables settings please)

```
groovy -n -e "println line.toLong()" data.txt
```

*Error :*

```
Caught: java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
```

data.txt is there in that directory (verified using TAB key)

---

Not sure why its throwing Error ????

[data.txt contains raw data in following format]

1

2

3

4

Comment: Do the file have those line breaks?

Comment: Yes............ I am using Java 7 version and groovy 2.2.2 version

Comment: Even if I use line.reverse() , its throwing the same error ....

Comment: Can you try reading the file manually? `groovy -e ' println new File("data.txt").text '`

Comment: Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: data for class:
 script_from_command_line

Comment: There is something wrong with your script. How did you wrote the quotes?

Comment: While executing
groovy -e " println new File("data.txt").text " [see double quotes around execute script]

M getting this Error :

Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: data for class: script_from_command_line

Comment: I wrote "[double quotes] that enclosed the println statement [Starting double quote is before println and Ending double quote is at the end of the command]

and I have also enclosed data.txt in double quotes same as I mentioned in above comment....

Comment: I am using groovy 2.2.2 version ...and that wont be problem surely or Will it ????

Comment: Are there empty lines between the lines containing the numbers?

Comment: Run it in debug mode and post the full stacktrace: `groovy -d -n -e "println line.toLong()" data.txt`

Comment: If I use println System, command gets succed.. If I use println line , throws an error....

Comment: FULL STACKTRACE IS AS FOLLOWS :


Caught: java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
        at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Win32FileSystem.java:414)
... etc etc

Comment: @Robby Do you know whats this :

Invalid argument at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method) at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Win32FileSystem.java ... ????

Comment: It's a native Windows method that's throwing the exception. No idea why, I'm not a Windows user myself.

Comment: Sorry Robby. I might hoped much from you. Sorry 4 that. and BTW, thanks a lot for a Quick response and an immediate help. and Thanks to JamesA and Will too for finding out some time to help me.

Comment: Those double quotes, at least in Linux, are wrong. You need to wrap the whole script in single quotes and the println string in double quotes, or the whole script in double quotes and the println string in single quotes. Trying changing one of then or executing the command line exactly as i wrote in my comment

Answer (score 1):

I tried to duplicate the problem with Groovy 2.3.6 and Java 1.7.0_60 on Linux and had no issue:

```
$ echo -e "1\n2\n\3\n\4" > data.txt
$ groovy -n -e "println line.toLong()" data.txt
1
2
3
4
```

With a non-existing file:

```
$ groovy -n -e "println line.toLong()" bogus.txt
Caught: java.io.FileNotFoundException: bogus.txt
java.io.FileNotFoundException: bogus.txt
```

With non-numeric data:

```
$ echo -e "a\nb\nc\nd" > data.txt
$ groovy -n -e "println line.toLong()" data.txt
Caught: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"
        at script_from_command_line.run(script_from_command_line:1)
```

And it even worked with CR/LF EOL:

```
$ echo -e "1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r" > data.txt
$ groovy -n -e "println line.toLong()" data.txt
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Mine is throwing IOException with Invalid argument.... I dont understand what the problem with this ....

Comment: Prashant2329, try using the `echo` command as JamesA proposes. Your file might have some problem.

Comment: Even if I pass wrong file name (i.e. Non-existing file) ,Unlike your's, it is throwing the same Invalid argument (IOException) ... Instead it should throw FileNotFoundException ........ Whats wrong ????

Comment: When I run 
echo -e "1\n2\n\3\n\4" > data.txt
this command, My data.txt overwritten with following data:
-e "1\n2\n3\n4\n"