# Unknown property - Groovy Exception

Tags: groovy

I am Newbie to Groovy.I am using java 7 and groovy 2.2.2 version. No problem with Environment variables settings.

I am trying the following in groovy shell :

```
hc = { println ""HI $it"" }

c=1..5

c.each hc
```

When I am executing third statement(c.each hc), it is throwing :

```
unknown property $it
```

I don't understand What will be the problem ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
hc = { println "HI $it" }

c=1..5

c.each hc
```

Don't know how Groovy will try to parse it exactly, but double double-quotes `""` have no meaning in Groovy. When using double quotes, either single `"` or triple `"""` will work.

Comment: It worked... thnx a lot..... Can you explain a little bit more... I am a newbie to groovy ....

Comment: And 1 more thing... Could you please take a Look at here also :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285715/groovy-script-error/25286112#25286112

Comment: Don't know how Groovy will try to parse it exactly, but double double-quotes `""` have no meaning in Groovy. When using double quotes, either single `"` or triple `"""` will work.

Comment: okay... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285715/groovy-script-error/25286112#25286112

Plz take a Look.....

Comment: Would you please take a Look at this too:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285715/groovy-script-error/25286112#25286112